How to remove right padding using css
I have the following page (see attached). How can I remove the right padding using css? Ideally I want all the boxes to flow to the center without the right margin.
Here's the code:
    <div class="details">
       <div class="tile">
       </div>       
       <div class="tile">
       </div>
       <div class="tile">
       </div>
       <div class="tile">
       </div>
   </div>

   .details {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: self-end;
   }
   .tile {
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px; 
       display: inline-block;
   }



Is that really right padding or right margin?  Is what you really want a "super centered" set of boxes or just as many as can fit; those centered?

So I want to fit as many as possible per row but I want the whole box to be centered on the page so there is no right margin.

justify-content: center; ?  (or space-between or space-around if you prefer?)

You can use a grid within a grid and then set it to whatever number of rows or columns you want; here I used 3 columns and auto rows but that is a choice.  Simple border an style just to show what is where.  I put a scroll on the container but that can be whatever style choice you want.


body {
  --main-size-block: 6.25em;
}

body,
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  border-color: #0000FF;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.details {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(var(--main-size-block), auto));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(var(--main-size-block), auto);
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.tile {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: var(--main-size-block);
  height: minmax(var(--main-size-block), fit-content);
  background-color: #0A0A0020;
  border: solid 1px#0A0A00;
  padding: 1em;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="details">
    <div class="tile">1 is me</div>
    <div class="tile">2</div>
    <div class="tile">3</div>
    <div class="tile">4</div>
    <div class="tile">5 is the middle</div>
    <div class="tile">6</div>
    <div class="tile">7</div>
    <div class="tile">8</div>
    <div class="tile">9</div>
    <div class="tile">10 save it for the best for last and make it longer.</div>
  </div>
</div>



